# Install RRDtool 1.4.7 on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, yum, dependencies, rrdtool, zenoss

I'm trying to install Zenoss core 4.2.3 which requires RRDtool 1.4.7.
CentOS 6 comes with RRDtool 1.3.8

So, I've downloaded the RPM rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm and tried to install it, which gave me the following output:

```
[root@automation-zenoss tmp]# rpm -i rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
libdbi.so.0()(64bit) is needed by rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64
perl(RRDp) is needed by rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64
perl(RRDs) is needed by rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64
perl(Time::HiRes) is needed by rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64
```

So I've downloaded perl-rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm and tried to install it which gave me the following output:

```
[root@automation-zenoss tmp]# rpm -i perl-rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
rrdtool = 1.4.7 is needed by perl-rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64
```

It seems like I'm stuck in a loop where I can't install RRDtool since it requires something that requires the RRDtool.

Is there a way to install RRDtool 1.4.7 on CentOS 6?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't there a proper repository available where you downloaded these files? If yes, activate it and just use `yum install rrdtool`. Otherwise, try to install all packages at the same time.

Comment: How can I install the packages at the same time?

Comment: `yum install <package1> <package2>`....  These packages seem to come from the Repoforge extras repo. Use it.

Comment: This is not a circular dependency. rrdtool does not require perl-rrdtool. It _does_ require several other things which you haven't attempted to install. Again, use repositories in the manner in which they were intended, and you will not run into this sort of problem.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was able to find the rpm https://pkgs.org/centos-6/repoforge-x86_64/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm.html and use it to install the rrdtools

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded https://pkgs.org/centos-6/repoforge-x86_64/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm.html and installed it.

I was able to install RRD tools by using the command
    yum -y --enablerepo='rpmforge*' install rrdtool-1.4.7

Answer (score 1):

As the first failed dependency was: `libdbi.so.0()(64bit)`, installing or updating `libdbi` would have been my first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/dag/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

yum install rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

yum -y --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras install rrdtool-1.4.7
```